# how to assign equation number to the last equation only and align it to the right

Tags: equations, numbering

```
\begin{align*}
\epsilon_x (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_x(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k) + \\
\epsilon_y (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_y(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k) +  \\
\epsilon_z (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_z(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k) -  \\
(\epsilon_x(i - 1, j, k) + \epsilon_x(i, j, k) + \epsilon_y(i, j - 1,k) + \epsilon_y(i, j, k) \\
  + \epsilon_z(i, j, k - 1) + \epsilon_z(i, j, k))\varphi(i, j, k) + \\
  h^2\lambda(i, j, k) k^2 \varphi(i, j, k) = - \frac{4\pi\rho(i, j, k)}{h} \label{eq:2}
\end{align*}
```

How to assign equation number to the last equation only and align it to the right?

[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `IEEEeqnarray*` environment from the [`IEEEtrantools` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetrantools). This environment provides a `tabular` like syntax and it is possible to achieve most types of alignment using this environment.

The `*` version of the environment is used for equations without numbering. To insert an equation number in such an environment, `\IEEEyesnumber` command can be used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}{\epsilon_x (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_x(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k) +{}} \\
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}{\epsilon_y (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_y(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k) +{}} \\
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}{\epsilon_z (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_z(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k) -{}} \\
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}{(\epsilon_x(i - 1, j, k) + \epsilon_x(i, j, k) + \epsilon_y(i, j - 1,k) + \epsilon_y(i, j, k) } \\
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}{ {} + \epsilon_z(i, j, k - 1) + \epsilon_z(i, j, k))\varphi(i, j, k) + } \\
    h^2\lambda(i, j, k) k^2 \varphi(i, j, k) &=& - \frac{4\pi\rho(i, j, k)}{h} \IEEEyesnumber\label{eq:2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I missed the part of your question about right alignment. Do you want something like this?

[image]

This can be achieved using only one right-aligned column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{r}
    \epsilon_x (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_x(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k) +{} \\
    \epsilon_y (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_y(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k) +{} \\
    \epsilon_z (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_z(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k) -{} \\
    (\epsilon_x(i - 1, j, k) + \epsilon_x(i, j, k) + \epsilon_y(i, j - 1,k) + \epsilon_y(i, j, k) \\
    {} + \epsilon_z(i, j, k - 1) + \epsilon_z(i, j, k))\varphi(i, j, k) + \\
      h^2\lambda(i, j, k) k^2 \varphi(i, j, k) = - \frac{4\pi\rho(i, j, k)}{h} \IEEEyesnumber\label{eq:2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks all for your input. all the solutions worked!

Answer (score 6):

You could also nest an `aligned[b]` environment inside an `equation` environment. That way, a single equation number will be assigned to the entire `equation`, and this equation number will be placed on the bottom row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:2}
\begin{aligned}[b]
&\epsilon_x (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_x(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k)  \\
&\quad+ \epsilon_y (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_y(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k)  \\
&\quad+ \epsilon_z (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_z(i, j, k)\varphi(i + 1, j, k)  \\
&\quad- [\epsilon_x(i - 1, j, k) + \epsilon_x(i, j, k) + \epsilon_y(i, j - 1,k) + \epsilon_y(i, j, k) \\
  &\qquad+ \epsilon_z(i, j, k - 1) + \epsilon_z(i, j, k)]\varphi(i, j, k)  \\
  &\quad+ h^2\lambda(i, j, k) k^2 \varphi(i, j, k) = - 4\pi\rho(i, j, k)/h 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can issue `\nonumber` or `\notag` to avoid setting a number inside an `align` (and friends):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  &\hspace*{-3em}
   \epsilon_x (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_x (i, j, k) \varphi(i + 1, j, k) \nonumber \\
  &{} + \epsilon_y (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_y (i, j, k) \varphi(i + 1, j, k) \nonumber \\
  &{} + \epsilon_z (i - 1, j, k) \varphi (i -1, j, k) + \epsilon_z (i, j, k) \varphi(i + 1, j, k) \nonumber \\
  &{} - \bigl( \epsilon_x (i - 1, j, k) + \epsilon_x (i, j, k) + \epsilon_y (i, j - 1, k) + \epsilon_y(i, j, k) \nonumber \\
  &{} + \epsilon_z (i, j, k - 1) + \epsilon_z(i, j, k) \bigr) \varphi(i, j, k) \nonumber \\
  &\hspace*{5em} + h^2 \lambda(i, j, k) k^2 \varphi(i, j, k) = - \frac{4 \pi \rho(i, j, k)}{h}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The additional spacing elements is just for a somewhat better layout.